# Is the word "whilst" not used in U.S. English?

Tags: american-english, british-english

In my spare time I sometimes help out a good friend of mine. He is a professional translator, self-employed so he can pretty much pick his own assignments, which is a good position to be in, but I digress. We are both Dutch, and the jobs I help him with usually involve translating from English to Dutch, but occasionally from Dutch to English.

The question is just out of curiosity. Is there a definite answer to it?
Again, is the word "whilst" used in UK English only? or in U.S. English as well?

Comment: AmE does not use *whilst*.

Comment: It is not "used" in the US, but it is understood, and is reasonably acceptable in translated works and the like.

Comment: One encounters it in writing occasionally, but never in speech.

Comment: Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=while%3Aeng_us_2009%2Cwhilst%3Aeng_us_2009%2Cwhile%3Aeng_gb_2009%2Cwhilst%3Aeng_gb_2009&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhile%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhilst%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhile%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhilst%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0), for what it's worth, suggests it's not very common in either dialect.

Comment: And [a similarly constructed Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=among%3Aeng_us_2009%2Camongst%3Aeng_us_2009%2Camong%3Aeng_gb_2009%2Camongst%3Aeng_gb_2009&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camong%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camongst%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camong%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camongst%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0) shows that the situation is almost strikingly identical for _among(st)_, except that word is in decline in all its forms in general.

Comment: "Whilst" may still be used in AmE in the dialects of the mountain dwellers of the Appalachians. ("Hillbillies," in the vernacular) Couldn't say for sure - ain't encountered none in person, lately.

Comment: As with many things in life, absolute statements about English tend to miss out on corner cases. I have heard "whilst" in AmE, but it's rare, and almost always done for effect, not as a natural part of the language.

Comment: I think when used by an American, it generally comes across as affected and pretentious. British people of any class can say it and sound natural.

Answer (score 1):

*Whilst* is considered an archaic form of *while*.  As a native speaker of Appalachian English in Northern Alabama, I have never heard this used in conversation.

Answer (score 1):

To check the distribution of un-self-conscious usage of *whilst* by questioners and answerers at English Langauge & Usage, I ran a search for the word *whilst* in the EL&U search box. The search yielded slightly fewer than 600 matches. Then I excluded all instances that occurred in the context of discussions of *while* vs. *whilst* or other U.S. English vs. UK English topics. And finally (to the extent my memory allowed) I took only the first instance of *whilst* usage from any poster; in other words, I counted WS2 (for example) only once, even though he uses *whilst* often (and naturally).

My goal was to see how the usage of *whilst* broke out by country among posters who have identified their place of origin or current location in their site biography. To arbitrarily limit the size of the experiment, I decided to stop the counting when the number of posters whose home/residence was unstated reached 100. Overall, by the time I reached 100 unique whilst users of unknown residence, I had also tallied 85 users who had specified their place of origin or current residence.

Here is how the numbers came out for *whilst* users:

> Unknown residence: 100
>
> United Kingdom: 45
>
> United States: 11
>
> Australia: 5
>
> India: 5
>
> Canada: 4
>
> Netherlands: 2
>
> Sweden: 2
>
> Croatia: 1
>
> Czech Republic: 1
>
> Germany: 1
>
> Hong Kong: 1
>
> Iran: 1
>
> Italy: 1
>
> Japan: 1
>
> Malta: 1
>
> Mexico: 1
>
> Oman: 1
>
> Vietnam: 1

So on EL&U, according to the results of my experiment, a person who uses *whilst* in a non-*whilst*-related post is about four times as likely to live in the U.K. as to live in the United States. The numbers for *whilst* are undoubtedly higher proportionately in my experimental group than they would be in the wild (so to speak) among native U.S. English speakers. One of the U.S. matches, for example, came from a post-doc researcher at Texas A&M—and I know for a fact that no native of College Station, Texas, says *whilst*. As John Lawler observes in a comment beneath the question, use of *whilst* in spoken English by native U.S. English speakers is extremely rare.